# pandas DataFrame multiple substrings match, also put the particular matched substring for a row into a new column

Tags: python, pandas, substring, match, string-matching

I'm trying to extract some records from a survey response DF. All of these records need to contain at least one of some key words. For example:
Now I have a dataframe df:

```
svy_rspns_txt
I like it
I hate it
It's a scam
It's shaddy
Scam!
Good service
Very disappointed
```

Now if I run

```
kw="hate,scam,shaddy,disappoint"
sensitive_words=[unicode(x,'unicode-escape') for x in kw.lower().split(",")]
df=df[df["svy_rspns_txt"].astype('unicode').str.contains('|'.join(sensitive_words),case=False,na=False)]
```

I will get result like

```
svy_rspns_txt
I hate it
It's a scam
It's shaddy
Scam!
Very disappointed
```

Now how can I add a column "matched_word" to show what exact string is matched so I can get the result like:

```
svy_rspns_txt            matched_word
I hate it                hate
It's a scam              scam
It's shaddy              shaddy
Scam!                    scam
Very disappointed        disappoint
```

Comment: What if multiple words match?  should the `matched_word` column show all of the words, or just the first word that matches?

Comment: @TimJohns now I'm only required to do the first word appeared. But it's nice if you can provide me some advice to show all matched words. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a generator expression with `next`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["I like it", "I hate it", "It's a scam", "It's shaddy",
                            "Scam!", "Good service", "Very disappointed"]})

kw = "hate,scam,shaddy,disappoint"

words = set(kw.split(','))

df['match'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: next((i for i in words if i in x.lower()), np.nan))

print(df)

                text       match
0          I like it         NaN
1          I hate it        hate
2        It's a scam        scam
3        It's shaddy      shaddy
4              Scam!        scam
5       Good service         NaN
6  Very disappointed  disappoint
```

You can filter for valid strings via [`pd.Series.notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) or by noting `NaN != NaN`:

```
res = df[df['match'].notnull()]
# or, res = df[df['match'].notna()]
# or, res = df[df['match'] == df['match']]

print(res)

                text       match
1          I hate it        hate
2        It's a scam        scam
3        It's shaddy      shaddy
4              Scam!        scam
6  Very disappointed  disappoint
```

Comment: Can't you just do `res = df[df['match'].notna()]`, to make it more clear?

Comment: @TimJohns, Yep, that works too, and clearer, thanks. I usually use `pd.Series.notnull`.